# Create a span element (const pokemonData) and put the pokemon objects properties inside of it?

Tags: javascript

I am a bit confused what they mean where it says `put the pokemon objects properties inside of it?`

Object example

```
 const pokemon = {
  name: name,
  type: type,
  region: region
}
```

Not sure how to put the object property inside the span, is the innerHTML doing it?

```
const pokemonData = document.createElement("span");
pokemonData.innerHTML = `${pokemon.name} - ${pokemon.type} - ${pokemon.region}`
```

[image]

Comment: It's your code; is it doing it?

Comment: I updated the question with a screenshot, I am not sure if that is considered the span element having the pokemon objects properties inside of it

Comment: I don't quite understand. What do you mean? It's a span element; are those the expected properties?

Comment: Yes those are the properties, this is the what needs to be done ``Create a span element (const pokemonData) and put the pokemon objects properties inside of it ``

Comment: It looks like you have achieved that.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that, I was overthinking it and thought the ``Create a span element (const pokemonData) and put the pokemon objects properties inside of it`` was saying something else.

Comment: What says it, in the first place? Is it a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.

```
const pokemon = {
 name: name,
 type: type,
 region: region
}

const pokemonData = document.createElement("span");
pokemonData.innerHTML = `${pokemon.name} - ${pokemon.type} - ${pokemon.region}`
```

I was over thinking it, the value of the of the `name`, `type`, `region` is the object properties in the created span element.
`${pokemon.name} - ${pokemon.type} - ${pokemon.region}`